# Making a copy of google spreadsheet

Tags: java, google-docs, google-docs-api, google-sheets

I am trying to copy an existing spreadsheet document by following the example on the [documentation page](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/documents-list/#copying_documents). I use `ClientLogin` method to authenticate. My first step is to get the template doc:

```
SpreadsheetService service =
    new SpreadsheetService("MySpreadsheetIntegration-v1");
service.setUserCredentials(USERNAME, PASSWORD);

DocumentQuery query = new DocumentQuery(new URL(
    "https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/spreadsheets/private/full")); 
query.setTitleQuery("template"); 
query.setTitleExact(true); 

SpreadsheetFeed feed = service.getFeed(query, SpreadsheetFeed.class);
List<SpreadsheetEntry> spreadsheets = feed.getEntries();

SpreadsheetEntry template = spreadsheets.get(0);
```

All is fine. In `template` I have the document. Then I try to create a new one:

```
SpreadsheetEntry newDoc = new SpreadsheetEntry();
newDoc.setTitle(new PlainTextConstruct("new copy"));
newDoc.setId(template.getId());
service.insert(new URL("https://docs.google.com/feeds/default/private/full"), newDoc);
```

I get `AuthenticationException: Token invalid`. If I use `https://docs.google.com/feeds/default/private/full` to retrieve the document, it fails right there. So I guess `docs.google.com/...` requires some sort of higher privileges but how to obtain them?

Comment: @isola009 No, not yet. I get this error all the time. Now I am trying with OAuth.

Comment: Ok, let me know if you fix it. I will try with OAuth2 as well.

Comment: @isola009 With OAuth 1.0a and scope `https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds https://docs.google.com/feeds` I manage to copy spreadsheet document with the above code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you can't create documents with `ClientLogin` authentication model. Use Oauth.